# Why doesn't Django 2.1 login_required work when parameter is present

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-authentication

In urls.py I have:

```
path('/admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('/admin/login', login_required(admin.site.login)),
path('/customlogin/', include('customlogin.urls', namespace='customlogin'))
```

This redirects to a custom authentication view, specified in `settings.LOGIN_URL`.

When you go to `/admin` it redirects to `/admin/login/?next=/admin`, which does not redirect to `LOGIN_URL`. But when you go to `/admin/login` directly, everything works correctly.

Note: This worked correctly in Django 1.11.

Comment: It’s probably your switch from `url()` to `path()` that changed the behaviour, not the upgrade to Django 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the admin login url, your path should have a trailing slash. You also have to move your path above `admin.site.urls`, so that Django uses your decorated view.

```
path('/admin/login/', login_required(admin.site.login))
path('/admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Comment: I thought this was going to work, but it actually had the opposite effect...login_required no longer works for /admin/login/ either. Its something about that / at the end that seems to be breaking login_required.

Comment: You also have to fix the order.

Comment: Fixed it! Why does order and '/' matter in Django 2?

Comment: The order and slash have always mattered, Django 2 didn’t change that. Perhaps you were missing the dollar in your regex, e.g. `url(^admin/login', ...)`, so it was matching urls with and without the slash.